# Can an attribute attached to a Django model get information about a given record?

Tags: python, django

I have a class object attached as an attribute to a Django model. For the purposes of the question, let's assume it looks something like:

```
class Foo(object):
    def bar(self):
        print "Does things here"

class Task(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'tasks'

    foo = Foo()
```

Is it possible for me to access values of a specific record from the foo attribute? So, for example, if I have something like:

```
task = Task(name="Get things done", user=JordanReiter)
newest_task = Task.objects.filter(user=JordanReiter).order_by('-pk')[0]
```

Then I could have some function `spiffy` on the `Foo` class so I could run something like:

```
newest_task.foo.spiffy()
```

And the `spiffy` function would know that in this case the value for name was "Get things done", etc.

Basically I'm wondering whether attributes can know information about the instance that calls them, or only the class that calls them. And, of course, if this is possible, how do I access the values for the instance?

In a perfect world, the `foo` attribute would have access to info about the `Task` class as well as the `newest_task` instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you might want a [descriptor](http://martyalchin.com/2007/nov/23/python-descriptors-part-1-of-2/). They're classes that implement special methods that are called when getting or setting, and are passed the parent instance.

Comment: Is there any good source code out there that shows descriptors in active use? Most examples just have "I set the value!" "I got the value" methods which aren't very instructive.

Answer (score 0):

You would make `Foo` a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) so that it knows about `Task` inherently.

Comment: Except that Foo isn't a manager and isn't involved in any manager functions.